how this error would be resolved in build React Native
During building my project, i am facing following error.
Error Build Failed to install the app.
Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Settings file 'C:\Users\Deekshant\OneDrive\Desktop\react-native\AwesomeProject\android\settings.gradle' line: 2 * What went wrong: Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings'] > java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Deekshant\OneDrive\Desktop\react-native\AwesomeProject\android\.gradle\8.8\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10-a091e9f6-d9c8-4f6d-8c3c-49e1c902024c) to immutable location (C:\Users\Deekshant\OneDrive\Desktop\react-native\AwesomeProject\android\.gradle\8.8\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10) * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 1m 51s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I tried changing SDK Path env also but it didn't help.
Looking for help.
Thank you
